# Returns null on CachedRowSet query

Tags: hikaricp

I always get an error when I try to use the method query();.
The error is basically a NullPointerException, but idk how it's possible..

The query method:

```
public CachedRowSet query(final PreparedStatement preparedStatement) {
    CachedRowSet rowSet = null;
    if (isConnected()) {
        try {
            ExecutorService exe = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
            Future<CachedRowSet> future = exe.submit(() -> {
                try {
                    ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.getResultSet();
                    if(resultSet != null) {
                        CachedRowSet cachedRowSet = new CachedRowSetImpl();
                        cachedRowSet.populate(resultSet);
                        resultSet.close();
                        preparedStatement.getConnection().close();
                        if (cachedRowSet.next()) {
                            return cachedRowSet;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            });
            if (future.get() != null) {
                rowSet = future.get();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return rowSet;
}
```

How I call this method by using 'ResultSet data = mySQL.query(statement);'
This doesn't give any errors, but whenever I use the variable data, as example:
"if(!data.next())"
It gives me the following error.

Error:

```
[22:46:28 ERROR]: Could not pass event PlayerJoinEvent to Hestia v1.0-SNAPSHOT
org.bukkit.event.EventException
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:302) ~[PaperSpigot-1.7.10-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-PaperSpigot-1f7d532]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62) ~[PaperSpigot-1.7.10-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-PaperSpigot-1f7d532]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:509) [PaperSpigot-1.7.10-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-PaperSpigot-1f7d532]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:494) [PaperSpigot-1.7.10-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-PaperSpigot-1f7d532]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PlayerList.c(PlayerList.java:300) [PaperSpigot-1.7.10-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-PaperSpigot-1f7d532]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PlayerList.a(PlayerList.java:185) [PaperSpigot-1.7.10-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-PaperSpigot-1f7d532]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.LoginListener.c(LoginListener.java:119) [PaperSpigot-1.7.10-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-PaperSpigot-1f7d532]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.LoginListener.a(LoginListener.java:44) [PaperSpigot-1.7.10-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-PaperSpigot-1f7d532]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.NetworkManager.a(NetworkManager.java:192) [PaperSpigot-1.7.10-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-PaperSpigot-1f7d532]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.ServerConnection.c(ServerConnection.java:81) [PaperSpigot-1.7.10-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-PaperSpigot-1f7d532]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.v(MinecraftServer.java:795) [PaperSpigot-1.7.10-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-PaperSpigot-1f7d532]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.DedicatedServer.v(DedicatedServer.java:307) [PaperSpigot-1.7.10-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-PaperSpigot-1f7d532]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.u(MinecraftServer.java:643) [PaperSpigot-1.7.10-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-PaperSpigot-1f7d532]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:549) [PaperSpigot-1.7.10-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-PaperSpigot-1f7d532]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:628) [PaperSpigot-1.7.10-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-PaperSpigot-1f7d532]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at me.quartz.hestia.data.system.profile.ProfileMySQL.createPlayer(ProfileMySQL.java:68) ~[?:?]
    at me.quartz.hestia.listeners.PlayerJoinListener.playerJoinEvent(PlayerJoinListener.java:18) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:298) ~[PaperSpigot-1.7.10-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-PaperSpigot-1f7d532]
    ... 14 more
```